# Why is my flute squeaking when moving bottom finger

Tags: technique, flute

I just bought a Native American flute and it plays beautifully with one problem. When I remove the finger from the bottom hole, sometimes there is a loud squeaking and the flute goes high pitched.  I played around with it and sometimes I can get the note I want, but the squeaking happens even when I make sure that all of my holes are covered and I am breathing slowly. It only happens when removing and placing my fingers on the bottom hole. Is this user error?  I can’t seem to keep it from happening frequently.

Comment: Hi, please post the make/model (unless this was a custom item from a random seller), and a photo showing in detail the hole in question.

Answer (score 2):

This shouldn't be happening. Either the block is wrongly adjusted or the instrument is defective. If adjusting the block doesn't fix the problem, you should return the flute to the place you bought it for replacement or a refund.

Comment: Or, at least, have a [semi] skilled player verify it's the axe and not the OP's fault.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft Those flutes are so easy to play, there's almost no way that something like that could be due to the way the player is blowing, but the positioning of the block does make a lot of difference.

Comment: true that.  I just tend to be very cautious until any "data point" is verified :-)